# i18n and Services,do they play nice together?

Tags: i18n-l10n, services

I have been reading on how a i18n and Services module play together, and it seems this area is riddled with problems. This is what I found so far: http://drupal.org/node/208939
Is it possible to create and retrieve multilingual nodes with services?